# How to set timeout for a task, and then abort it

Tags: c#, async-await, task

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"The main thread is {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Person p = new Person { Name = "Apple" };
        try
        {
            cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));//limited to 3 seconds
            DoSth(p).Wait(cts.Token);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        Console.WriteLine(cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested);
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task DoSth(Person p)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            p.Name = "Cat";
            Thread.Sleep(5000); 
            
            Console.WriteLine($"The async thread is {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see the code as above, I got the output:

```
The main thread is 1
True
The async thread is 4
```

It seems that method is still running after cancellation?
Is it possible to abort the task in some time?
When I'm trying to use Thread.Abort(), I got an alert that the method is obsolete.

Comment: You're cancelling _waiting for_ the task, you're not cancelling the task. We can see this because the task itself has no cooperative cancellation and doesn't take a `CancellationToken`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads

Comment: Things I find strange here: the use of `Thread.Sleep` in `async Task Main` instead of `await Task.Delay`. Calling `DoSth(p).Wait(cts.Token);` instead of `await DoSth(p)` or perhaps `await DoSth(p, cts.Token);`  if you modify it to take a `CancellationToken`. The empty catch that just swallows any exceptions isn't great either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to abort the task after 3s you need to send the token to the function. If you use `Task.Delay` and send in the token that will throw an exception on cancellation and abort the task.

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"The main thread is {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Person p = new Person { Name = "Apple" };
        try
        {
            cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));//limited to 3 seconds
            await DoSth(p, cts.Token);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message); //task was canceled
        }
        Console.WriteLine(cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested);
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task DoSth(Person p, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        p.Name = "Cat";
        await Task.Delay(5000, ct); //Will throw on cancellation, so next row will not run if cancelled after 3s.
        Console.WriteLine($"The async thread is {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```